# Linux iSCSI Target MCS

Tags: linux, windows, iscsi, targetcli

I have a Linux Server hosting an iSCSI target.
The iSCSI Initiator is a Windows 10 Desktop

When connecting with the Windows 10 Machine im unable to start MCS. (Too many connections)
Windows also shows me that the max allowed connections is just 1.
[image]

On the Linux server im running a plain fileio backed iSCSI Target with 2 Portal IPs.
[image]

On the Windows Desktop I have both Portals added under the Discovery Tab.
[image]

Am I missing some setting on either end?

Update: Same issue with Windows Server 2019 even with installed MPIO Driver.
[image]

Update: Added Screenshots

Update: tried connecting 2 different clients to the same target and that worked fine.

targetcli showed 2 sessions aswell.

Update: Tried using a blockio device but still didnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it working.

To get MC/S working with LIO (Linux IO) you have to set MaxConnections in your iSCSI settings file (generated when exiting targetcli)

It's located in /etc/target/saveconfig.json
You will find a value of "MaxConnections": "1" and you can change it to fit your setting.

Windows now correctly reports having two available connections

Answer (score 4):

You need to enable MC/S @ both sides: target AND initiator.

Please check this step-by-step guide below on how to do that.

[https://moodjbow.wordpress.com/2011/10/30/mpio-and-mcs-under-windows-–-configuration-in-a-nutshell/](https://moodjbow.wordpress.com/2011/10/30/mpio-and-mcs-under-windows-%E2%80%93-configuration-in-a-nutshell/)

Comment: I tried the steps. Sadly still no luck.

On Windows 10 and Server I still can only open one connection and on Server I'm only able to open a single session on MPIO.

Answer (score 3):

Windows 10 as a client OS does not officially support iSCSI multipathing. You can use workaround from technet - https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-us/1b5ec2f8-8ba8-4320-8cac-89fc623f83b9/windows-10-mpio?forum=win10itprosetup , but on your own risk.

Comment: You have to differentiate between MCS and MPIO.
MCS is included in Windows 10

I just tried the same with MPIO driver installed on Windows Server 2019 and the same Problem.
I can only open 1 Connection.

Actually more questionable is that even MPIO will only use one connection to the Target.

Comment: So you're unable to connect more than one connection even to the Windows Server?  Did you try to create another target on WS and connect it to the Linux client?

Comment: @Stuka My target is running on a linux server. When using MPIO on Windows server, it only opens one session. I tried connecting 2 different clients to the same target and that worked fine. targetcli showed 2 sessions aswell. 

I also created another blockio device but that didnt work either

Comment: i installed a Windows Server 2019 with a target and it shows the same problem on a Windows 10 Client